# Why does "kill -9 0" end my console session?

Tags: process, kill, ps, init

I just wonder why `kill -9 0` ends my tty console session?

What exactly is PID 0, it is not listed on a `ps aux`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`kill`ing 0 isn't killing the pid 0.  Instead it is an option in `kill` to kill all processes in the current group.  With your command you are killing everything in the process group ID (GID) of the shell that issued the `kill` command.

from the `kill` man page:

```
   pid... Specify the list of processes that kill should signal.  Each pid
      can be one of five things:

          ...

      0      All processes in the current process group are signaled.
```

Comment: A sobering option that really teaches you to RTFM at that :)